# Not able to use Raspberry pi as a FM transmitter

Tags: raspbian, gpio, update

I have refered to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6smyUoLugsg .The problem is, in it he has used a Raspberry pi (first model). I tried the things he told me but it wouldn't work. I urgently need help. I have followed each and every step in the video

If anyone knows a patch or knows how to edit it, it would be awesome.

Comment: Hello and welcome. If possible try to be more specific than "it would not work". What's not working? What did you try? What are the error messages? ...

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware nobody has got PiFM to run on the Pi2.

There is no particaular reason it should not work on the Pi2.

However the people who know the required changes seem reluctant to publish.  Mainly, I think, because of the doubtful legality in some juridstictions of transmitting radio waves with multiple harmonics.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out
https://github.com/SandPox/fm_transmitter

I tested & found it working.
Just a wire can transmit in my whole house

Answer (score 1):

This is the one I've been tinkering with yesterday and it seems to work fine on my RPi3. Don't have a 2 to test with. Give it a try.

https://github.com/markondej/fm_transmitter

Comment: I'm trying to get bluetooth output piped to fm_transmitter but can't get it to work yet :-(